# Creating an XSL stylesheet to make file path attribute clickable

Tags: xml, xslt

In a number of directories such as "AAA", "BBB" and "CCC" there are hundreds of monthly dated folders such as "201209", "201310" and "201701". In each and every one of these monthly folders there are hundreds of PDF-files - all named as a GUID (123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000).

That's the situation on the disk. So every PDF-file has a path like "AAA/201704/{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}"

Out of a major XML-file I have been able to split up every casenumber to a folder such as "KN2012_00435", "FN2015_01234" and "BN2017_08762" and in every one of these folders there are one XML-file for every PDF-file attached with that casenumber.

In those XML-files the location of the PDF-file is stated as an XML attribute DocumentID="{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}".

My first problem is to create a XSL stylesheet to make that attribute clickable. Could it be done?

My second problem is that I would like to put these casefolders in a directory up in the directory tree from the PDF-files.

In the file:

```
//casenumbers/KN2012_00435/{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}
```

.... there is a clickable GUID going to ....

```
//docs/AAA/201704/{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}
```

Could that be done?

Comment: Please try to find a better title for the question. I'm leaning towards having this question migrated to [SO] as it's more related to programming, but probably it's fine to stay here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've provided enough information to make it possible to give you any code, but yes, in XSLT 2.0 this is possible. You need XSLT 2.0 so that (a) you can use the collection() function to return all the files in a directory, and (b) you can use the xsl:result-document instruction to write multiple output files.

When you say you want something to be "clickable" I assume that means you are generating HTML and viewing it in the browser. But that's a guess. Things can also be clickable, for example, in PDF. I wouldn't know how to do that, though it can probably be done.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the first part of my problem by this piece of code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//dbo.Documents/@DocumentID">
    <tr bgcolor="#FBF5A4">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></td>
        <td><a href="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The second problem is to make an adjusted "href" so that it would refer to (in a Windows file system) K:\docs\anydirectory\anydirectory\{.}